# Visual Studio Windows Application, SQL Query hangs, then returns nothing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlcommand, dataview, sqldataadapter

I am developing a windows application in VS (C#) and I'm having an issue.  One of the commands I execute is a stored procedure in SQL Server.  Typically when I execute the procedure it takes about 7-12 seconds and returns a result.  Occasionally I execute the command and it hangs for about 30-50 seconds and returns an empty rowset (when there should be results).  There is no timeout error, it just seems to give up and return blank results.

Here is another interesting tidbit... This new application is based off of an older program (I don't have the source code to) that executes the same SQL procedure.  The old program will also hang for longer periods occasionally, but it doesn't "give up" after about 50 seconds.  It waits until it gets the result even if it takes longer occasionally.

I have extensive experience in SQL Server and am confident that end of things is correct (credentials, permissions, the SQL code itself etc).  I feel like I am missing some kind of property or something in Visual Studio that changes how it is handling the SQL end.  Below is what I am doing in VS.  The SQL procedure essentially queries a table to get some parameters, then executes an xp_cmdshell command to search our file server for documents and returns a list of the documents that were found.

```
//Search for  documents
    private void search(string item)
    {

        DataSet ptDataset = new DataSet();
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=myLogin;Password=myPassword")) //
        {
            cn.Open();

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FindItemDrawings", cn); 
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", item);

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                adapter.Fill(ptDataset);
                myDataView = ptDataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;

                dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataView;

                cn.Close();

            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

I need to figure out why I am not getting results so I can resolve the issue.  I am fairly new to C# / visual studio so I assume I am just missing some property or setting that will help me out, but for all my searching I just keep hitting a brick wall.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Using Sql Profiler to check what's happen on the Sql Server side, another path could be incrementing the CommandTimeout. However having some kind on file system interaction on the server could lead to all possible scenarios like file access permissions problems, locking with other programs, busy server, etc...

Comment: You are not setting the timeout on your SQL connection. So if you have a query that takes longer than the default it **will** time out and return no data - though you should be getting the exception logged to your console.

Comment: As @ChrisF said, it sounds like your connection is timing out.  before you fill your adapter, add this `cmd.CommandTimeout = 3000;` (adjust to your needs, if it's still timing out, continue to jump this value up until it no longer times out).  That being said, it sounds like you might want to take a look at the SQL that's being called.  It sounds like it's probably in need of some tweaking to improve performance.

Comment: I can adjust the timeout....I would have expected an error were that the case.  The SQL is fine, the slowness is caused by a file system search, depending on the folders / structure it can take a few seconds.

Comment: Please provide the stored procedure code that "executes an xp_cmdshell command to search our file server for documents and returns a list of the documents that were found." so we can review and make suggestions, if applicable.